# Navigation Validation in Swift iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6

[image: This is a simple project which showing the navigation from one controller to another.]

[image: This picture shows that after I've pressed sign in without filling in the text field, it still redirects to next controller with alert message]

I've made a validation that a user can't login if both text field is blank. However, the alert message is popped out but it still will navigate to the next controller. How to overcome this problem? This exists while both text field is blank and just only showing the alert message, not navigating to next controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a segue from the Login button to the next scene. So what you'll want to do is implement

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool
```

then check if the identifier is equal to the segue identifier from the Login button.

I would move your validation into this method and return false if the validation fails, otherwise true.

Comment: Then what should I write into the Login Button function? I'm still new to the Swift, not really adopt to the navigation still.

Comment: If you already have a segue setup for it then you don't need to do anything in it

Comment: Thanks dude, I did it, appreciate :) It doesn't need the action of the button to navigate to next controller, just implement the function that you've suggested to me. Thank you very much.